# Getting wrong Kubernetes pod status through client API

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core

I am trying to get the Kubernetes pod status through Kubernetes  C# client library [client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/). One of my pods is a crash loop in the state. But the status of the pod from API is running. How to get the actual status of the pod?

Iam using

c# library .
  
Code is

```
using k8s;
var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig();
var client = new Kubernetes(config);
var namespaces = client.ListNamespacedPodAsync("cronjob").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
foreach (var ns in namespaces.Items)
{
   var status = ns.Status.Phase;
   Console.WriteLine(status);             
}
```

Output is

```
 Running 
 Running
```

But the actual result is while using kubectl command is

kubectl get pods -n cronjob

```
test3-1625640480-9vjg4         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          5m51s
test1-cron-1625640600-mrqcg    0/1     Completed          0          4m39s
```

Comment: Just a small remark, did you try and post a question on the github? Folks over there may have a better clue. Seems like your code is right looking at the namespace examples.

Comment: sorry . i didn't post on github

Comment: wondering too; looks like the only status that will be returned are the following : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase

it might to be provided by another endpoint - i haven't yet found out which one. did you?